# C#: How to view Outlook e-mail on page

Tags: c#, view, outlook, email

I'm thinking about providing a capability in my web app for a user to attach an Outlook e-mail item (.msg file when you save it) to a journal entry using a journaling tool built into the application. Associating the file with the journal entry and storing the contents are things I think I can handle, but I'd also like to provide them with a way to view the e-mail right in the application.

So if a user is viewing a past journal entry, notice that an e-mail is associated with it, they can click and view right there. This whole Outlook integration is brand new to me, and I've done enough research to know to import the Outlook Interop and use the classes there. But that's about as far as I've gotten.

I'm not looking for a comprehensive solution, but does anyone know if there is a reason I might not be able to do this? If I can, which classes in particular are going to allow me to do this? Or is there an article that covers this that I've missed?

In particular, I think I'm interested in how to use an outlook e-mail file to build an e-mail object on the server. From there, I imagine it should be a matter of accessing the object's properties and outputting the contents in the view. Unless there's something I may need to do with html-based e-mails.

Thanks.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120104/getting-a-object-reference-error-in-prod-only-when-trying-to-use-the-word-documen/5121896#5121896). Don't ever use Office Interop from an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

since outlook saves emails as msg files
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/reading_an_outlook_msg.aspx maybe this can help. and also specs:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912.aspx