# Instantiating the Application object of Interop.Word hangs the Webservice

Tags: web-services, windows-server-2003, com-interop, office-automation

I am using `Interop.Word` version 12 for doing some operation in a word document. My WebService is built in .Net v4.0. 
The code starts with instantiating an Application object as shown below :

```
  Application _wordApp = new Application();
```

which later in the code uses it to create a Word Doc:

```
 _oDoc = _wordApp.Documents.Add(ref tempFilename, ref _missing, ref _missing, ref _missing);
```

This is all implemented in a Webservice but the service gets hang in instantiating the Application object itself inside the webmethod .

The WebService works fine in my Dev environment but this issue happens once I deploy the Web Service on Windows Server 2003 which is using  IIS 6.0.

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757. Short answer, "don't do this".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a Object Reference error in prod only when trying to use the Word DocumentClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120104/getting-a-object-reference-error-in-prod-only-when-trying-to-use-the-word-documen)

Comment: what do you mean "did not help"? The article is telling you why you can't do this. You should "try" not calling Office Automation from server applications.